# Changing frame of one of two sections of UICollectionView - ios

Tags: ios, layout, view, uicollectionview

I am trying to configure my `CollectionView` to have one section be differently sized than the others. I have two sections. Lower part should show a number of cells simultaneously and the upper section should only show one cell at a time but be scrollable to reveal more cells one by one.

I tried to play with the .`frame` property of the `CollectionView` but obviously it is not the right approach as it changes the appearance of the whole view.

I also tried to retrieve the `FlowLayout` object and see if I can get it from there. Did not find a way.

Neither the section `Insets` are the answer so far ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to use two uicollectionviews for upper and lower section, instead of using only one.

Comment: It is not an answer to my question. I asked how to do this and not what will be the other solution.

Comment: Sorry. I'll write suggestion via comment next time.